# plot_likert - The center or origin isn't in the logical place - "I want "Very satisfied & Satisfied | Less satisfied"

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I am trying to build a likert plot on survey data and the only thing that I can't figure out is how to move that origin so the Satisfied and Very Satisfied are on the same side.  Can anyone help with that?

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

dta <- structure(list(`Medical: Overall` = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Don't Use", "Less Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), `Medical: Plan Options` = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Don't Use", 
"Less Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), 
    `Medical: Rx Costs` = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Don't Use", "Less Satisfied", 
    "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor"), `Medical: Mail Order for Rx` = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Don't Use", 
    "Less Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"), class = "factor")), row.names = 10:20, class = "data.frame")

clrs <- c("#FD6467", "#ABDDDE", "#81A88D")

plot_likert(dta, catcount=3, cat.neutral = 1, sort.frq="neg.desc", 
            reverse.colors=T, values = "show", show.n=F, digits=0, show.prc.sign=T, 
            show.legend=T, geom.colors=clrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `plot_likert`

```
?plot_likert
```

**Note**

Note that only even numbers of categories are possible to plot, so the "positive" and "negative" values can be splitted into two halfs. A neutral category (like "don't know") can be used, but must be indicated by cat.neutral.

This function does not handle an odd-number of Likert responses.

Comment: Well, I want the neutral category to be "Don't Use" because that's removes it from the visual of satisfied vs not without ignoring it.  Thanks!

Comment: I see. The true issue is that `plot_likert` expects an even number of Likert choices.

Comment: I was hoping that I could use theme options or geoms from ggplot2 to adjust that.  But I might have to just remove the neutral category and let it be the 4th option.